# Como implantar e executar o liquibase?

Tags: java, liquibase

Como faço para implantar o liquibase? e executá-lo? tenho projetos em java e uso o banco oracle.

Esta ferramenta tem a possibilidade de gerar a partir do arquivo de versao do estado do banco, tem como gerar em .SQL??

Poderá utilizar este arquivo para voltar a uma versão antiga do banco?

Aguardo retorno obrigada.

Answer (score 2):

Existem diversas formas de utilizar Liquibase em seus projetos. É possível utilizar a **[linha de comando](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html)** para gerar, XML a partir de um SQL e vice-versa, existem outros formatos como YAML, JSON, entre outros.
Além da linha de comando, também é existe um **[plugin Maven](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/)** para executar durante o build do projeto. E também possui **[suporte a CDI](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html)** que possibilita a execução direto no deploy da aplicação no servidor.

Abaixo segue um exemplo da forma mais comum de utilização do Liquibase para o versionamento de DB.

```
   <changeSet author="nome-author" id="meu-changeset-id-1">
        <createTable tableName="user">
            <column name="uuid" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="age" type="INT" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Todas as demais alterações à tabela do banco são apenas adicionadas a um novo "changeSet", possibilitando de se efetuar [**roolback**](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) a qualquer momento.

Note que ele não é uma ferramenta de geração / tradução de queries. Liquibase é um poderoso framework de versionamento.